# Laravel5.2 withCount not working

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, relation

I tried to use withCount() method just like the documentation and always i get this error :
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withCount()

```
public function index($id)
{
     $data = \App\Institute::find($id);

    if(!$data)
        return response()->json(['message' => trans('system.notFound')])->setStatusCode(404);

    $users = \App\MainArea::withCount('institute')->where('institute_id',$id)->get();

  return $users;


}
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: Are you sure you're on 5.2?

Comment: I'm sure, can you try the same issue ?

Comment: I've just tried it with one of my projects, it works for me

Comment: can you guess what is the problem in my case ?

Comment: Well the only thing I can think of is you're on the wrong version. If you're on 5.2 I don't see what the problem could be. I've tried to pass wrong arguments but the error-message is not the same

Comment: Your `\App\MainArea` extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, right?

Comment: the version of laravel is  '5.2.39' , thanks for your help .

Comment: yes it extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

Comment: thanks man, i solved it by updating the composer wooow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by updating the composer.
composer update